# Accessing only part of a list

Tags: list, scala, set

I have a function which returns List

```
List( Int, Int, Set(Int)).
```

How can I pass it to another function and access the `Set(Int)` part only?

Comment: Do you mean List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])]?

Comment: I recommend checking out the `List` docs - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access only the last item use appropriate method:

```
scala> val xs = List( Int, Int, Set(Int))
// xs: List[Object] = List(object scala.Int, object scala.Int, Set(object scala.Int))

scala> xs.last
// res0: Object = Set(object scala.Int)
```